List folders' content takes long time
Ubuntu 23.10, two Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB.
They seem in good health:
$ sudo smartctl -t long -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-28-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB
Serial Number:                      S5GYNX0TC00116E
Firmware Version:                   5B2QGXA7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 500.107.862.016 [500 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      6
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500.107.862.016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            168.251.899.904 [168 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 bc21b523fd
Local Time is:                      Thu Apr 25 12:20:07 2024 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0057):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0f):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.49W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.48W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0     200
 2 +     3.18W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0    1000
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4      500    9500

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        29 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    9.297.397 [4,76 TB]
Data Units Written:                 5.225.569 [2,67 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 79.100.919
Host Write Commands:                52.658.924
Controller Busy Time:               210
Power Cycles:                       917
Power On Hours:                     165
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   58
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               29 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               28 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged

Often, not always though, when I browse my files using the default Gnome "File" application it takes several seconds to list the content of my directories. I don't use encryption or other advanced features.
I don't know what are the potential root causes and what log files I could inspect to find them out.
For example I tried to grep nvme0n1 from dmesg but it founds nothing relevant.

That's hard to diagnose, but a first thing to do is to use gio list --attributes=ATTRS FOLDER_NAME where you keep adding common attributes until you find the one responsible for increasing the loading times substantially. Otherwise it could be a bug with Files.
